# How to Deal with Peaks and Valleys on Scale Data

Tags: normal-distribution, scales

I've got a questionnaire/scale from 0-8, let's say it's a mood scale (0 = no depression, 8 = most depressed ever felt), subjects fill in a bubble along the scale, but the numbers aren't there, only text. There are peaks on all the even numbers, and valleys on the odd numbers when looking at a stem and leaf or histogram.. (this is mostly true across the distribution, and I think it's because people tended to select the values have text above them, only the even numbers on this particular questionnaire)... It looks like is causing this data to violate visual and numerical tests of normality... (plus it's positively skewed)

Do I A) change it to a categorical variable (e.g. low, medium, high), or B) force collapse the responses in the valleys to be the same values as the peaks, or C) run the analysis as if it's distributed normally even though it's not....  or D) another option I have not listed.

Looking forward to responses!!

Comment: For whom are you doing the analysis?  How rigorous does your audience expect you to be?  Is there any chance you'll be redesigning the survey, and if there is, how important will it be that you maintain comparability from report to report?  What, for you, are the consequences of normality violation?  Will you be conducting inferential tests?  Will you be reporting p-values (which might be affected by the shape of distributions)?  Cheers -

Comment: This is related to my dissertation analysis, which will be sent out for publication, so the highest level of rigor is needed.  Data is collected, and will not be re-collected.  These analyses may be considered separate from the parent study, but these issues might also impact parent study analyses...not sure yet.. so I might have a little more leeway...  I will be reporting p-values.  Violating normal assumptions may be acceptable, but I will need to defend all choices made...  n = 100 (fyi)...

Comment: I would not choose B, as it does violence to the data.  Now, more questions :-)  Which analyses do you have planned?  How skewed are the data points (could you display them?) Remember that a variable can often be transformed.  Also remember that in regression or anova it's the residuals, not the original values, that need to be normal in order for estimates and p-values to be accurate.  And, if the respondents are not a random sample of the population of interest....

Comment: thanks, rolando2, that's where I went, and good news on residuals being normal, there is some major positive skew, and platykurtosis on a few predictors...